# Change default wallet address in ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js

I am trying to change the default address used by the `wallet` to send transactions.

`let wallet = Wallet.fromMnemonic('hurdle cloud ...').connect(provider);`

`wallet.address // 0xfB98c...`

How do I change the `wallet`'s address to another address from the same private key? I feel like this should be obvious but digging through the documentation it doesn't appear possible.

**Edit**

Given that a single private key only has a single public key (and public address), the question needs adjusting. How would it be possible to generate new private keys (and therefore public addresses) from this mnemonic using ethers.js?

Comment: A given private key has only a single public key and a single public address mapped to it.

Comment: There are theoretical collisions of course, since the domain of private keys is larger than the domain of public addresses. But finding such a collision is supposed to be computationally impossible.

Comment: Thanks. Would it then be possible to create new a private key from this same mnemonic to generate a new public address?

Comment: I'm not sure how mnemonics work, but my common sense is that they too are 1-to-1 correspondent with private keys (i.e., each mnemonic yields a single private key). I think that the only idea about them is that they are easier to remember or something like that. But again - I'm honestly not sure about their role in the system. With web3 scripting (and even more-so with smart contract developing), they have no use AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [HDNode](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-advanced.html#hdnode) which is defined as:

> A Hierarchical Deterministic Wallet represents a large tree of private
>   keys which can reliably be reproduced from an initial seed. Each node
>   in the tree is represented by an HDNode which can be descended into.

When you use this HDNode, you can change the path variable you give it in order to get different private/public key pairs that are derived from this HDNode.

You can learn more about the path variable [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70017/can-someone-explain-the-meaning-of-derivation-path-in-wallet-in-plain-english-s). For Ethereum wallets, the default address / private key used is at path: `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`. To follow the outlined protocol, for ethereum addresses, you can change the account and/or index fields: `m/44'/60'/1'/0/0` `m/44'/60'/0'/0/1`

```
let HDNode = require('ethers').utils.HDNode;

let mnemonic = "radar blur cabbage chef fix engine embark joy scheme fiction master release";

let masterNode = HDNode.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);

let standardEthereum = masterNode.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0");

console.log(standardEthereum.publicKey);
console.log(standardEthereum.privateKey);

//account 0 index 1
let accountZeroIndexOne = masterNode.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/1");
console.log(accountZeroIndexOne.publicKey);
console.log(accountZeroIndexOne.privateKey);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks Steven. Trying to ween myself from web3+HDWalletProvider. This did the trick for me.